# How to use Counter in python without showing numbers

Tags: python, list, counter, python-collections

I have little problem with python's Counter library. Here is an example:

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = ['x','y','z','x','x','x','y', 'z']
print(Counter(list1))
```

Output of it:

```
Counter({'x': 4, 'y': 2, 'z': 2})
```

My question is how to receive the output without quantity of repetitions?

What I want to get is:

```
Counter('x', 'y', 'z')
```

Comment: Why are you using a counter, if you don't want to *count*?

Comment: So what I supposed to use? I want sorted output from the most common elements to the rarest.

Comment: "I want sorted output from the most common elements to the rarest" - see, this is important information that you should have told us in the first place. That rules out options like a set, which seem like the obvious choice from just what's in the question.

Comment: why not use `set` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the keys from `most_common()`:

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'z']

print(Counter(list1).most_common())  # ordered key/value pairs
print(Counter(list1).keys())  # keys not ordered!

keys = [k for k, value in Counter(list1).most_common()]
print(keys)  # keys in sorted order!
```

Out:

```
[('x', 4), ('y', 2), ('z', 2)]
['y', 'x', 'z']
['x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the different elements of a list, you can just convert it into a set.

That being said you can also access the keys of the Counter dictionary using the method `keys` to obtain a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider the output of Counter as a dictionary, we can get only the strings by getting only the keys of the dictionary:

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = ['x','y','z','x','x','x','y','z']
values = Counter(list1).keys()
print(values)
```